# Strongloop - how to disable process management explorer

Tags: strongloop

I've successfully deployed to Strongloop docker server. Everything seems fine, except one thing, that the Strongloop management interface (port 8701) is exposed to the public.

Is there anyway to hide the interface and swagger api from public, so that nobody can access it directly, but through http+ssh?

**EDIT 1:** I've tried to block port 8701 on centos 7, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8701 -j DROP
```

I think there should be a better way rather than manually blocking port.

**EDIT 2:** I realized it's not deployable if port is blocked. Besides, I found this command in Strongloop's doc to initialize the basic auth

```
curl -sL https://strong-pm.io/docker.sh | sudo bash -s STRONGLOOP_PM_HTTP_AUTH=username:password
```

However, the question still remains, is there any way to disable pm completely from http request (http+ssh is ok)?